# Отсутствует перевод заголовка раздела “Bookmarks” на странице Активности

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника, закладки

Отсутствует перевод заголовка раздела “Bookmarks” на [странице Активности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14846.
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14847.
3. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14848.

Comment: Почему вопрос дубликат? Following и Bookmarks разве одно и тоже. Здесь ответ правильный дан. Ссылки на строки с переводом о закладках. А в вопросе про  Following тот же ответ, опять про закладки. Почему???

Comment: @AlexR. в том вопросе и про Bookmarks тоже есть.

Comment: На картинке? то то я не нашел ничего. Мы же всех ругаем за картинки с кодом, ошибками и т.д.

Comment: @AlexR. да, нужно бы и в заголовок добавить)

Comment: А с ответом что? Все три ссылки на строки о закладках, где Following?

Comment: @AlexR. нет пока времени. Чуть позже добавлю остальные строки, если никто до меня этого не сделает.

Comment: Даа. Но ответ то уже засчитан. Как-то не очень понятно. Вроде есть ответ, а вроде и не совсем. Вы уж не забудьте про перевод, пожалуйста )